# Is it "query on ...." or "query about ...."

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, collocation

Which is grammatically correct?

> 1. Query **on** Physics Final
> 2. Query **about** Physics Final

Say if this was a subject field in an email you're about to send to a teacher. Which would be better English, or are they both acceptable?

The meaning of the word "query" here is question or enquiry, not doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Both prepositions are acceptable in this context. I believe *"query about"* is more frequent, but I'd use both here.

Comment: I'd use 'query concerning' if it was a general query ('is one allowed to wear a wig when taking the exam?') but 'query about/on' if more concretely related ('will it be written in Greek?').